# Datatable don't retain the values edit in the other rows when adding a new row

Tags: jsf-2

I have problem of data table values not being retained when adding new rows to the datatable. Do I have to have my bean in request scope so is there a way to retain the updated datatable values during subsequent add? In my case the bound list (using the value attribute of datatable) is always empty during every add row action.

Bean:

```
public class Students {
  private StudentService service;

  @PostConstruct 
  public void init() {
    list = service.list();
  }

  public void add() {
    list.add(new Student()); 
  }

  public void save() {
    service.save(list); 
  } 
}
```

Form:

```
<h:form> 
    <h:dataTable value="#{students.list}" var="student">
        <h:column><h:inputText value="#{student.name}" /></h:column>
    </h:dataTable> <h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{students.add}" /> 
    <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{students.save}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: There is a similar problem already posted but i cant implement the soultion because my bean must be in request scope only..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118734/datatable-dont-retain-the-newly-added-object/8994875#8994875

Answer (score 0):

If you have request bean, one way is to have valueChangeListener="#{bean.ajaxCall}" on that component and have a empty ajaxCall method in your bean. This way the value is stored via an ajax call in the backing bean and will survive an update to the datatable.

Comment: Thanks Ravi.. I am curious to know if this is possible without ajax call.I already tried with ajax it worked too.. but the problem during the final submit or save(to Db) the data table values are null(ie the list binded to the table).. i am trying to learn..

Comment: Can you post some code of your xhtml file and the save method of your bean

Comment: it looks similar to this public class Students {
       private StudentService service;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        list = service.list();
    }

    public void add() {
        list.add(new Student());
    }

    public void save() {
        service.save(list);
    }
   }
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{students.list}" var="student">
        <h:column><h:inputText value="#{student.name}" /></h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{students.add}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{students.save}" />
</h:form>

Comment: If i have the list object in session it seems to be working but i was wondering how to get the list binded to the data table without having the list in session.

Comment: I think your action method is not matching the method expression. The return type should be String. Or you can just use actionListener which has a method expression of return type void. Ref:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361684/jsf-2-1-valueexpression-in-action-attribute)